# The portal is having issues getting an authentication token. The experience rendered may be degraded

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azureportal, azure-authentication

[image]

**Error Message**:

```
The portal is having issues getting an authentication token. The experience rendered may be degraded.

Additional information from the call to get a token:
Extension: Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring
Resource: loganalyticsapi
Details: The extension 'Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring' has not defined the resource access 
for resource 'loganalyticsapi' in the extension's configuration, or in the portal's configuration.
```

When I create the resource in Azure, the access is not showing in the IAM of that resource and also getting authentication issue.

I'm the owner of my subscription.

#### Updated:

[image]

I'm getting the same issue - no role assignments after any resource creation in Azure Portal.

I'm the Owner of My Azure Free Subscription.

Could anyone help me!

Comment: what is it that you attempt to do in the keyvault that you get the authentication issue related notification?

Comment: I Just created the Key Vault and opened it, immediately I got the authentication issue notification in the Azure Portal.

Comment: I have given more details in the question. Could anyone please help me, as this issue is critical

Comment: @JashuaCriss you are listed as a classic service administrator which means you have full access to both resources you are showing in your screenshots. Do you have any management operations you tried that failed? The authentication notification you are seeing would only effect monitoring/log analytics scenarios according to the information in the notification.

Comment: Additionally, you can give yourself Owner permission on the subscription given the current permissions you have and you would see that propagated to every resource you create. More information on the service administrator access you currently have can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/classic-administrators

Comment: You can also use Portal self help to see if you have any issues that could contribute to the authentication token issue. https://portal.azure.com/selfhelp

Comment: Hi @BrianHauger, all the self help checks are passed. As I mentioned, i'm already owner of my subscription and the management operation I want to do is generating the secret in the keyvault and other but after creating any resource, i'm getting this authentication issue notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the notification correlates with the timing of the resources you were creating, it does not necessarily imply that any issues you see are directly caused by what the notification is saying. [Correlation doesn't imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation). Essentially, if you don't see any issues with the result of the operation you are performing (besides that authentication notification showing up), then what that notification is describing isn't actually causing an issue for that case. The service health section in the portal confirms that it wasn't a technical issue (See the last update for the service health issue).

[image]

If you are having issues with creating secrets in a Key Vault these are the steps you can follow:

1. Determine what permission model your key vault is using by clicking on the Access configuration menu item and looking at the Permission model section.

   [image]
2. If you are using the Azure role-based access control permission model, you can give yourself one of the required RBAC roles mentioned in [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli) that is suitable for what you want to do. This is the default selection and by default you won't have access to keys, secrets, or certificates until you assign yourself one of the specific key vault RBAC roles. If you are using the vault access policy, you can [use these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal) to set the correct permissions in vault access policy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same Azure error message when opening my App Service Plan, and all the Metrics (CPU %, Memory %, etc, are zero).
My App Service works OK so far, Application Insights also work OK.
It's been this way for about a week (starting around Feb 20, and ongoing).